# How to get data back from reducer with a async action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

Redux newbie here 
So I have this code that dispatches an async action and it uses promise to handle the request

So here is `mapDispatchToProps`

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
      fetchUserList: () => {
        console.log('---In fetchUserList---');
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_USER_LIST,
          payload: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            console.log('xhr: ', xhr);
            xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:5000/data/fetch/users');

            xhr.onload = () => {
              console.log(' --- in onload function ---');
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
              resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            }
            xhr.onerror = () => {
              console.log(' --- in onerror function ---');
              reject(xhr.statusText);
            }
            xhr.send();
          })
        });
      }
```

what it does is it fetches array of json objects from the server which get map to

```
mapStateToProps
```

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {

  return {
    userlist: state.list_reducer,
  };
};
```

Now here is the component I used both of above:

```js
class Profile extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listRender: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log('In render: ');
    console.log(this.props.userlist);
    return (
      // basic list rendering template
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {

    this.props.fetchUserList();
    this.setState({
      listRender: true
    });
  }
```

Now It can see from the above that I use `fetchUserList()` in `componentDidMount()` to fetch data from the server and data does get send to the reducer

Here is the `list_reducer.js`:

```js
export default function list_reducer(state = {
  operation: '',
  userlist: []
}, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_USER_FULFILLED":
      console.log("FETCH_USER_FULFILLED");
      console.log(action.payload);
      return {
        operation: 'success',
        userlist: action.payload
      }


    case "UPDATE_USER_DETAILS_FULFILLED":
      return {
        operation: 'success',
        userlist: action.payload
      }


    case "DELETE_USER_FULFILLED":
      return {
        operation: 'success',
        userlist: action.payload
      }


    case "REGISTER_USER_FULFILLED":
      return {
        operation: 'success',
        //userlist: 
      }

    default:
      return { ...state
      }
  }

};
```

Now instead of receiving newly fetched userlist I get the default data that is passed to reducer in `this.props.userlist` (`mapStateToProps`)

So the question is **how do I get** the newly fetched list instead of the **default state data** that is given to the **reducer**.

Comment: Did you have any luck with my answer?

Comment: Well I am still trying to make above work redux has a lot of stuff going on at the same time it becomes harder to grok for noobs like me but hey thanks for the answer man I can use it for future reference.

Comment: Right, but the above isn't the way you should do it, my guy.

Answer (score 2):

When making async calls with Redux I use [Thunks](https://medium.com/@stowball/a-dummys-guide-to-redux-and-thunk-in-react-d8904a7005d3)

> By default, Redux action creators don’t support asynchronous actions
>   like fetching data, so here’s where we utilise Redux Thunk. Thunk
>   allows you to write action creators that return a function instead of
>   an action. The inner function can receive the store methods dispatch
>   and getState as parameters.

So, if you wanted to make an API call, our action would look like this.

**Actions.js (or your equivalent)**

```
import axios from "axios";

export const receiveUserLift = json = {
  return {
    type: "RECEIVE_USERS",
    payload: json
  }
}

export function fetchUserList() {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios
      .get('http://localhost:5000/data/fetch/users')
      .then(response => {
        dispatch(receiveUserLift(response))
      })
      .catch(error => console.log("FetchUserList Axios Error", error))

  }
}
```

**Reducer** would include the following

```
case "RECEIVE_USERS":
  return Object.assign({}, currentState, {
    userList: action.payload
  });
```

**Component** would include the following

```
import { fetchUserList } from "WHERE WE DECLARED OUR ARE ACTION";

 class Example extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // You could use it anywhere, but this is how you would call the action
    this.props.fetch()
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.users === prevState.users) return null;
    return {
      users: nextProps.users
    };
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    users: state.userList
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => ({
  fetch: () => dispatch(fetchUserList())
});
```

**Sidenote**

Receiving the data in our component asynchronously requires that we make use of component lifecycle methods. You will see a lot of guides around the internet advising to use `componentWillReceiveProps` to do this, but this is going to be removed in future versions of React and replaced with `static getDerivedStateFromProps` you can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html)

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if (nextProps.users === prevState.users) return null;

    return {
            users: nextProps.users
    };
  }
```

**The above code serves as a rough guide**, but it is the general pattern that I've followed when dealing with Async API calls and rendering with Redux